# How do I build "gem install json"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I’m trying to build this tutorial — https://github.com/webguyian/bookstore, but getting a strange error, “An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.”  So I tried “gem install json -v '1.8.0'”

```
localhost:bookstore-master davea$ gem install json -v '1.8.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161007-50119-1huurrz.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                              ^
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/intern.h:797:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
        ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' (aka 'unsigned long (const char *, long)') [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/json-1.8.0/gem_make.out
```

I don’t know what this means or how to correct it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The version of the json gem you are using is not compatible with Ruby >= 2.2. Please use at least version 1.8.2 of the json gem with Ruby 2.3.

See the [Changelog](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for details about changes in functionality and compatibility.

That said, most of the time you don't even need an external gem to be able to work with JSON data in Ruby. The [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) shipped with Ruby's standard library is fully functional and compatible with Rails already.